# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 external Framework XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

Im trying to using an external SDK in the form of a framework, "ZoomSDK.framework".

I've added the framework to my "linked frameworks and libraries" and added all the other needed frameworks and libs but I seem to be getting an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_gzclose", referenced from:
      l38075 in ZoomSDK
  "_gzopen", referenced from:
      l38075 in ZoomSDK
  "_gzwrite", referenced from:
      l38074 in ZoomSDK
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

I've looked at similar posts regarding this issue but non of the solutions seem to work for me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT - I've

- included "-ObjC" in "Other Linker Flags"
- Set “C++ Language Dialect” to “Compile Default”
- Set “C++ Standard Library” to “Compile Default”
- Import system library: libsqlite3.dylib, libstdc++.6.dylib and CoreGraphics.framework

Non of these seem to fix the error.

Comment: How about try add -Objc in other link flags?

Comment: This doesnt work :( thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search tells me those symbols are defined in zlib.  http://www.zlib.net/manual.html

Try adding libz to the link library section of you project.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to have fixed it :)

Comment: Yes. This fixed my problem too. Life saver!